# Django Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)

Tags: django

I was wondering what's up with the `CSRF Cookie not set` error that Django throws at me all the time. I created a view (see below) that is a callback for a payment. I have no influence of what is being sent to that view. I have checked other posts on StackOverflow, but I don't think any apply to me. Most of them can just implement a csrf protection into their forms, csrf_exempt their views, or they use rest_framework.

```
class PaymentWebhook(View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
```

Now, I'm getting this error everytime when I do nothing about this function:

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /payment/webhook
```

Since this is about payments, can I just `csrf_exempt` this, or would that just open a security hole? By the way, I have even tried putting an exempt on this function, but it still throws that error.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Show your HTML that contains the form that submits to this view. Probably you have not set *inside this form* the `{% csrf_token %}`.

Comment: @nik_m That's just it, this view is not being posted to by any form of mine. This is posted to by the payment provider to return payment information

Comment: Then you should use the [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) decorator, without any security holes in mind.

Comment: @nik_m The other problem that occurred when I tried that, is that it will still tell me there is no csrf cookie set (same error). I put the `@csrf_exempt` on top of the post function there.

Answer (score 8):

I finally managed to get a POST through. I'm fairly sure I had already tested it, but it seemed to work now: I put an `csrf_exempt` in my `urls.py`.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

url(r'^payment/webhook$', csrf_exempt(paymentwebhook), name='payment-webhook')
```

Any other way it would not work for me for some reason. Thanks nik_m for the help, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You should decorate the `dispatch` method with the [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt), like this:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class PaymentWebhook(View):
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PaymentWebhook, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)  # for python 2
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)  # for python 3

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
```

or, based on [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class), you can clean it to:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class PaymentWebhook(View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
```

Comment: I have tried this before, and implemented it again like you suggested, but I still seem to get an csrf error

`Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /payment/webhook
INFO request "POST /payment/webhook HTTP/1.1" 403`

Comment: Are you sure this is a `POST` request? What the docs of the payment provider say about that request?

Comment: I am pretty sure. My console outputs a 403 POST error, and they explicitly say they're sending a POST request to this view

Comment: @dnsko Did you do a test post request to that url?

Comment: @itzmeontv I did, I'm getting the same Forbidden (403) there (with the message CSRF cookie not set)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i did ( import csrf_exempt )

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def add(request):
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Import csrf_exempt:

`from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt`

and then add the decorator:

`@csrf_exempt
    def your_function(request):
        ...`

I use this for my payment webhooks and it has not been an issue. If you are particularly worried about security you can get the IP address from the request and only process the webhook if it matches your payment providers IP. Usually obtained from their website/api docs.